# Which is better: GPT or RelGAN for text generation?

Tags: deep-learning, gan, nlp, text-generation, transformer

Based on my understanding, gpt or gpt-2 are using language model loss to train and generate text, which do not contains GAN.

So which is better: GPT vs RelGAN/LeakGAN/SeqGAN/TextGAN

I am so confused about this question.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.12686

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[Caccia et al., 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02549)], in general textual GANs are no rival for LMs regarding several quality measures. These are the conclusions of the paper:

> This research demonstrates that well-adjusted language models are a remarkably strong baseline
>   and that temperature sweeping can provide a very clear characterization of model performance. A
>   well-adjusted language model outperforms the considered GAN variants as evaluated on both local,
>   and more surprisingly, global metrics of quality and diversity. Our temperature sweeping framework
>   shares characteristics with a Receiver Operating Curve. Analogously, if one needed a single scalar to
>   compare NLG models, one could compute area under the curve and seek the model with the smallest
>   value (lower is better for our considered metrics).
>
> GAN-based generative models have been proven effective on real-valued data, however, but there
>   exist many difficult pernicious issues of moving to discrete data. These issues must be overcome
>   before they will improve over the strong MLE baselines. On the datasets and tasks considered,
>   potential issues caused by exposure bias were less than the issues of training GANs in discrete data.
>   GAN training may prove fruitful eventually, but this research lays forth clear boundaries that it must
>   first surpass.

This way, OpenAI's GPT and GPT-2 may be considered *superior* in text generation quality to current textual GANs.